# Help using Secant method in Matlab

Tags: matlab

So here is the funciton that I created:

function S = Secant(po,p1)
f = @(x) -x^3-cos(x);
tol = 10^-7;
n=1;
p=[];
p(n-1)=po;
p(n-2)=p1;
n=n+1;
p(n)=p(n-1)-f(p(n-1).*(p(n-1)-p(n-2)))/f(p(n-1)-f(p(n-2)));

while abs(f(p(n)))>tol && abs(p(n)-p(n-1))>tol
    n=n+1;
    p(n)=p(n-1)-(f(p(n-1).*(p(n-1)-p(n-2)))/(f(p(n-1))-f(p(n-2))));

end

This error is showing up and I'm not sure what is wrong... 
Error in Secant (line 6)
p(n-1)=po;

Comment: Just plug in the value of `n` ...

Answer (score 0):

function p = Secant(po,p1)

f = @(x) -x^3-cos(x);

tol = 10^-7;

p(1)=po;

p(2)=p1;

n=3;

while abs(p(n-2)-p(n-1))>tol

p(n)=p(n-1)-f(p(n-1))*(p(n-1)-p(n-2))/(f(p(n-1))-f(p(n-2)));

n=n+1;

end

end

Save the above code as a function Secant.m then type S=Secant(-1,1) in the command window. You will get an entire iteration like this

S =

Columns 1 through 7

-1.0000    1.0000   -0.5403   -1.8228   -0.6684   -0.7510   -0.8930

Columns 8 through 12

-0.8622   -0.8654   -0.8655   -0.8655   -0.8655

The last number  is your answer and you can see the convergence by plotting the values using the command plot(S) ! 
Substitute your answer  -0.8655 in the function and you will get a number very close to zero. If you want to see more digits in the code type "format long" in the command line then run the code. If you want to see the number with less digits as previously type "format short".
:There are many issues in your code many brackets were misplaced. You should learn MATLAB very seriously !